# How to join matrices like puzzle pieces in python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, concatenation, puzzle

I've got three puzzle pieces defined as a number of arrays, 7x7, in a following manner:

```
R3LRU = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
])
```

I am trying to join them by the following rules: 1111111 can be joined with 1000001, 1000001 can be joined with 1000001, but 1111111 cannot be joined with 1111111. Better illustration will be the following:

[image]

I have tried using `pd.concat` function, but it just glues them together instead of joining by sides, like this:

[image]

Or, in terms of code output, like this:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I suppose I would like to join by columns 6 and 0, or rows 6 and 0

How can I define "joining" sides, so that the pieces would join through the proposed rules?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. What does prevented from joining look like? What does the resulting output look like? How are pieces received (are they all known at start or are they generated in some way)? Are you looking to generate all valid joins? etc. etc.

Comment: I think the problem with people coming up with an answer is that you haven't clearly defined what you meant by "joining".  You may want to explain the nature of joining (that the joining of two 7x7 arrays yields a 13x7 array, explaining that one column is eliminated upon join, etc, and explain the expected result when 3 are joined horizontally)

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to concatenate if the last column and first columns match and then "overlap" both parts. I dont think, pandas is a good fit for this problem as you only need values, no columns or basically any features you would use pandas for.

I would recommend simple numpy arrays. Then you could do something like

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: R3LRU = np.array([
   ...:     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   ...:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   ...:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   ...:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   ...:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   ...:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   ...:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
   ...: ])

In [3]: R3LRU
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Get the last column of the first part and the first column of the second part

```
In [4]: R3LRU[:,0]
Out[4]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [5]: R3LRU[:,-1]
Out[5]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Compare them

```
In [6]: R3LRU[:,0] == R3LRU[:,-1]
Out[6]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])

In [7]: np.all(R3LRU[:,0] == R3LRU[:,-1])
Out[7]: True
```

If they are equal, combine them

```
In [8]: if np.all(R3LRU[:,0] == R3LRU[:,-1]):
   ...:     combined = np.hstack([R3LRU[:,:-1], R3LRU])

In [9]: combined
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Maybe your rules are a bit more complicated than a simple `==` comparison, but you can just make that `if` statement more complicated to reflect all rules you have ;)